# How to save special chars to string?

Tags: java, mysql, string, utf-8

I make aplication, and i must save user in mysql
but when user have name like this "Michał" (with polish char) in mysql he is save like this "Micha?" how to change this? in mysql i have enconding utf-8.

Here is my code:

```
public void save() {
    Connection conn = Main.getMySQL().getConnection();
    if (conn == null) {
        try {
            conn = Main.getMySQL().openConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    query.append("INSERT INTO `HelperTime` (`uid`, `name`,`time`,`idletime`) ")
            .append("VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ")
            .append(" `uid`=VALUES(`uid`), `name`=VALUES(`name`), `time`=VALUES(`time`), ")
            .append("`idletime`=VALUES(`idletime`)");
    try {
        st = conn.prepareStatement(query.toString());
        st.setString(1, uid);
        st.setString(2, name);
        st.setLong(3, time);
        st.setLong(4, idleTime);
        st.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Main.getMySQL().closeResources(null, st);
}
```

Comment: What programing language are you using? What does your code look like? Is your input string already in UTF-8 when you pass it to MySQL?  Please provide more details.

Comment: im programing in java but i must save name user to mysql

Comment: Again, please show the actual code you are using.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CvKhPbe4 i must use pastebing because this code has to many characters and when i save name to mysql 
it change special characters to "???"

Comment: That code is not even close to having too many characters to post on StackOverflow. I have put it in your question now.

Comment: ok thx but i try put this in comment xD

Comment: Did you read MySQL's documentation on [Using Character Sets and Unicode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html) for its Java API?

Comment: no im not reading but when i look now i see i can change utf8 to UTF-8 in java but how to this?

Comment: In the `getConnection()` call: `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1):

Question marks come from this:

- The client has a valid character (good), and
- The `SET NAMES` agrees with the encoding that the client has (good), but
- The target column's `CHARACTER SET` does not include the intended character (bad).

Examples:

- `latin1` handles only Western European characters; trying
  to put an Eastern European character or any Asian character in
  it won't fit.
- `latin2` and `cp1250` can handle Czech, so conversions between them are mostly OK,
  but not between either of them and `latin1`
- `utf8mb4` is a superset of `utf8`.
  Putting a utf8 character into utf8mb4 is ok, but the reverse
  will result in a '?' in some cases.

The characters that were converted to '?' can not be recovered from the table.

How to fix future `INSERTs`?

- Using `utf8mb4` on the table column(s) probably works in all cases.
- Otherwise, pick some `CHARACTER SET` for the table column(s) that reasonably matches the client data.

Encoding:

```
HEX('Michał') is '4D69636861C582'  'C582' is utf8 for 'ł'
```

Bottom line:  Change the `CHARACTER SET` for the table.